# Click a button using Selenium on python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click this button to export my data as a csv file. I'm using Selenium on python.
I can not figure out how to press the button because there is no id or name and the link changes every time.
Thanks in advance! [image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to scroll to that element. Like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'swissadme.csv')]")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
element.click()
```

If the locator above not enough try this instead:

```
"//a[contains(@href,'results/50881847/swissadme.csv')]"
```

Comment: I have already tried that but I got a syntax error

Comment: Are you sure you tried this exactly? What I wrote should be correct. At least from the syntax side.

Comment: Yes, I copied it exactly. The .click() is causing the error. When I run the code without the click() it doesn't give an error but when I add it I get an error.

Comment: Element Not Interactable Exception

Comment: OK, this is definitely not a syntax error! Do you have delay before clicking that element? Is this element presented on the screen or you should scroll to it to bring it to the view?

Comment: I do have a delay before clicking the element. I have to scroll down.

Comment: That's the issue! Moment

Comment: No it still doesn't work I am getting the same Element Not Interactable Exception error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233858/discussion-between-celin-younan-and-prophet).

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:-

```
elm = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[contains(text(),'Retrieve date:')]/a[contains(@href,''swissadme.csv)]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",elm);
elm.click()
```